# Writing a keyword for Automation in python scripting (RIDE)

Tags: python, frameworks, automation, switch-statement

Currently I would like to implement a keyword which just Opens my mobile application, for automating my test on mobile platform. I have done as below,

```
def open_app_from_homescreen(app_name):
    """ Opens application from homescreen 
    @precondition:Be on the homescreen of the device
    @param app_name: name of the application to open """
    try:
        if case =='App1' and app_name is not None:
            _Ui.application.openApplication("App1") 
        elif case == 'App2' and app_name is not None:
            _Ui.application.openApplication("App2")
        elif case == 'App3' and app_name is not None:
            _Ui.application.openApplication("App3")
        elif case == 'App4' and app_name is not None:
            _Ui.application.openApplication("App4")
        else:
            StepLogger.post_sub_step("No application name provided")
    except Exception as e:
        print_error("Failed to open Application" + app_name)
```

I have got hundreds of mobile applications to check using this keyword. Performance also needs to be considered here. Instead of using if-elif I have also felt that using dictionaries would do my job, but I am looking out for a more optimistic approach.
Basically I would like to implement a switch-case kind of functionality in my scenario.

I have got an idea to use a class, Not sure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

```
def open_app_from_homescreen(app_name):
    try:
        if app_name == None:
            StepLogger.post_sub_step("No application name provided")
        else:
            _Ui.application.openApplication(app_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print_error("Failed to open Application" + app_name)
```

I don't see why a `switch`-type statement is at all necessary.

I might be misunderstanding your intent, but it seems like you're using `for` as if to say, "for each case, do the corresponding bit below". This is not how Python works. A Python `for` means "for each element in the iterable, do *all* of the instructions below".

Comment: I would like to correct you here saying that I want to code something that resembles switch-case as in C programming.

Comment: But _why_? What benefit would that offer?

Comment: if case ('App1') and app_name is not None:
                _Ui.application.openApplication("App1") 
            elif case('App2') and app_name is not None:
                _Ui.application.openApplication("App2")
            elif case('App3') and app_name is not None:
                _Ui.application.openApplication("App3")
            elif case('App4') and app_name is not None:
                _Ui.application.openApplication("App4")

Comment: The above comment is useless. You're just rewriting what you wrote before as an `if`-`elif` statement. What benefit does this give you?

Comment: while automation,I dont want any performance issues. I have got hundreds of applications here to test. Suppose I am using if-elif and if my condition satisfies for 100th elif, that means all the 99 condition checks are waste of time & this would be a performance delay in automation.

Comment: I have found a fix for it. Thanks.

Comment: The issue is, you don't need to do an `if` test at all. Look at your code above: you're literally going, if the name is "app1" then run "app1", if the name is "app2" then run "app2", etc. That's completely pointless! You can just go `_Ui.application.openApplication(app_name)` and no matter what the app name is, it will try to launch an app with that name. You don't need an `if` statement, `switch` statement, or anything else.